# No colored png icons in treemacs (Doom Emacs)

Tags: doom, treemacs, icons

After reinstalling Doom Emacs several times I can’t find any way to make treemacs use the colored png icons of it’s own default theme. I always get monochrome icons.

[image]

How do I solve this?

Comment: Please don't post the same question in StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: Deleted on StackOverflow. Unfortunately there was no option to transfer the question from SO to emacs.SE. But to get the point: Do you have a solution for my problem?

Comment: Thanks. I don't have an answer to your question. Hopefully someone else will be able to help with that.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be due to a new variable added to Doom Emacs.

This sets the icons to be the familiar `all-the-icons` set.

```lisp
(setq doom-themes-treemacs-theme "doom-colors")
```